# Attempting to Index Match Match using VBA and failing

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match

I am attempting to identify the row and column of which the intersection is the data I want to retrieve, much like an index match match formula in Excel. My method is find the data in the column, get the column letter, and do the same with the data in the row and retrieve the row number. The problem I am having is that I have to reference a cell in a separate workbook where the macro is located to open another spreadsheet's name that changes with the month. I'm sure this whole thing's method is not very good, advice would be appreciated!

```
    Option Explicit

Sub RevenueTest()

'GVS1 Revenue Index Match Test

'DELETES & COPIES GVS1 revenue into P&R File

Dim GVS1 As String
GVS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Revenue").Range("v13")

Dim GVS1IS As String
GVS1IS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Revenue").Range("V7")

Dim GVS1Open As String
GVS1Open = Excel.Workbooks.Open(GVS1)

Dim Row As String
Row = Range("B5:B25").Find("Generation").Select.ActiveCell.Row

Dim Month As String
Month = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Revenue").Range("V4")

Dim MonthActual As String
MonthActual = Month & " Actual"

Dim Column As String
Column = Range("A1:P15").Find(MonthActual).Select.ActiveCell.Column

Dim GVS1RowAndColumn As String
GVS1RowAndColumn = Column & Row

'OPENS / Indexes and Copies Revenue

    Excel.Workbooks.Open (GVS1)
    Columns("C:Q").EntireColumn.Delete
    Range(GVS1RowAndColumn).Copy
        
        
'PASTES GVS1 revenue into P&R File
Dim Revenue As Worksheet
Set Revenue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Revenue")
     
ThisWorkbook.Activate
 Revenue.Range("D3:D11").Find("Revenue").Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  

End Sub
```

Comment: To clarify, is the problem that you need to enter the spreadsheet name in V13? If so, could you please give some examples of the changing names

Comment: No, I can see why that is confusing. I've solved the problem of modifying the filename with the changing month, the problem is attempting to "index match match" in VBA. I'm unsure if my method is sound, that and my code is likely completely wrong

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I properly understood this line

> My method is find the data in the column, get the column letter, and do the same with the data in the row and retrieve the row number.

But I do have a similar index match function in  my stock, take a look and modify it to your needs.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Return_value()

Dim Rmrks As Range, Itm_Rng As Range
Dim ItmLstPR As Range, ItmLstCode As Range

On Error Resume Next

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False

'they are table range btw like, "tabe_name[column_name]"
'in this range the return value will be pasted
Set Rmrks = .Range("Pip_Line[Remarks]")
'this range has the key word that needs to be matched
Set Itm_Rng = .Range("Pip_Line[Item_Code]")


' from "DMY_Pip_Line[Remarks]" range matched value will be returned
Set ItmLstPR = .Range("DMY_Pip_Line[Remarks]")

'we use "DMY_Pip_Line[Item_Code]" to match our keyword from "Pip_Line[Item_Code]" range
Set ItmLstCode = .Range("DMY_Pip_Line[Item_Code]")

        'Return Remarks
    Call Match_Value(ItmLstPR, Itm_Rng, ItmLstCode, Rmrks)
    
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

you can insert above code in a worksheet or in a module.

Paste below code in a module to get the final result.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Match_Value(ByVal ReturnVal As Range, ByVal LookupVal As Range, ByVal LookupRng As Range, ByVal PasteRng As Range)

Dim rng As Range, ResultRow As Long, foundcell As Range, ColmnDist As Long, FoundVal As String

'find column offset
ColmnDist = ReturnVal.Column - LookupRng.Column
ResultRow = PasteRng.Column - LookupVal.Column

On Error Resume Next
For Each rng In LookupVal
'return due placing location row
    Set foundcell = LookupRng.Find(rng.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
    
    'return value
    FoundVal = foundcell.Offset(0, ColmnDist).Value
    
    If Not foundcell Is Nothing And FoundVal <> vbNullString Then

       rng.Offset(0, ResultRow).Value = FoundVal

    End If
   
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand your code I have rearranged it. In order for you to understand your code I have commented it. To be clear: this is your code, unchanged! We just study.

```
Sub RevenueTest()
    'GVS1 Revenue Index Match Test
    'DELETES & COPIES GVS1 revenue into P&R File
    
    Dim Revenue             As Worksheet
    Dim GVS1                As String
    Dim GVS1IS              As String
    Dim GVS1Open            As String
    Dim Row                 As String               ' "Row" is an Excel object
    Dim Month               As String
    Dim MonthActual         As String
    Dim Column              As String               ' "Column" is an Excel object
    Dim GVS1RowAndColumn    As String
    
    GVS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Revenue").Range("V13")
    GVS1IS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Revenue").Range("V7")
    GVS1Open = Excel.Workbooks.Open(GVS1)           ' the workbook is an object: can't assign to String
    
    ' "ActiveCell.Row" is a number: why assign to a string variable?
    ' "Row" is an object: can't be the name of a variable
    ' don't select anything: create a range object instead
    ' "Find" returns a range object if successful
    '   if unsuccessful attempting to access that range must fail
    ' since you don't specify any sheet, 'Range("B5:B25")' is presumed
    '   to be on the ActiveSheet
    Row = Range("B5:B25").Find("Generation").Select.ActiveCell.Row
    
    Month = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Revenue").Range("V4")
    MonthActual = Month & " Actual"
    Column = Range("A1:P15").Find(MonthActual).Select.ActiveCell.Column
    GVS1RowAndColumn = Column & Row
    
    'OPENS / Indexes and Copies Revenue
    Excel.Workbooks.Open GVS1                       ' don't enclose arguments in parentheses
    Columns("C:Q").EntireColumn.Delete              ' columns are in the ActiveSheet
    Range(GVS1RowAndColumn).Copy                    ' Range is on the ActiveSheet
            
    'PASTES GVS1 revenue into P&R File
    Set Revenue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Revenue")
         
    ThisWorkbook.Activate                           ' no need to activate anything
    Revenue.Range("D3:D11").Find("Revenue").Select  ' no need to select anything
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select                 '
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Then I tried to re-write your code so that it might work. You can see how far I got. Look for the specification of the search ranges. They are on the `ActiveSheet`. Which is the *ActiveSheet*? We have no clue. But the code shows you how to approach the subject.

```
Sub RevenueTest_2()

    Dim GVS1Book            As Workbook
    Dim Revenue             As Worksheet
    Dim Fnd                 As Range                ' result of 'Find'
    Dim R                   As Long                 ' a row number
    Dim C                   As Long                 ' a column number
    Dim GVS1                As String
    Dim GVS1IS              As String
    Dim Month               As String

    Set Revenue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Revenue")    ' use "Set" to assign an object to a variable
    With Revenue
        GVS1 = .Range("V13").Value                  ' { always specify the property you want
        GVS1IS = .Range("V7").Value                 ' { here it's the Value
        Month = .Range("V4").Value                  ' "Month" is a string (like "April", not 4)
    End With
    
    Set Fnd = ActiveSheet.Range("B5:B25").Find("Generation")
    If Fnd Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox """Generation"" not found."
        Exit Sub
    Else
        R = Fnd.Row
    End If
    
    Set Fnd = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:P15").Find(Month & " Actual")
    If Fnd Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox """" & Month & " Actual"" not found."
        Exit Sub
    Else
        C = Fnd.Column
    End If
    
    Set GVS1Book = Workbooks.Open(GVS1)            ' GVS1 must be a path & name
End Sub
```

When the other workbook is opened I gave up. At that moment Excel will make that workbook the *ActiveWorkbook* and the sheet which was active when that workbook was saved will become the *ActiveSheet*. Your code immediately starts deleting columns on that unknown sheet. I couldn't get myself to do that.

As you complete the code I started, just remember that you don't need to activate the other workbook. Excel has done it for you and will give you back your original view when you close that book. Consider using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` not to show the active sheet. You don't need to select any worksheet on which you want to delete columns. But you do need to specify the worksheets on which you take action. I have strong doubt that my code looks for the two search criteria on the correct sheet. I specified `ActiveSheet` because that's what your code implied. So we're probably both wrong :-)

Comment: Thanks- I really appreciate the quick reply- I'll start to digest your answer because I'm a bit slow at this and get back to you if I have any questions!